# Unmarshalling SubElements from XML Response

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am trying to unmarshall a XML Response. It is in the following structure

```
<employee>
 <name> David </name>
 <age> 33 </age>
 <dateofjoin>
 <year>2012</year>
 <month>10</month>
 <day>01</day>
 </dateofjoin>
</employee>
```

Following is my Employee Class

```
public class Employee
{
    private Dateofjoin dateofjoin;

    private String name;

    private String age;

    public Dateofjoin getDateofjoin ()
    {
        return dateofjoin;
    }

    public void setDateofjoin (Dateofjoin dateofjoin)
    {
        this.dateofjoin = dateofjoin;
    }

    public String getName ()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName (String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge ()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge (String age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

The following is my dateofjoin class

```
    public class Dateofjoin
{
    private String month;

    private String year;

    private String day;

    public String getMonth ()
    {
        return month;
    }

    public void setMonth (String month)
    {
        this.month = month;
    }

    public String getYear ()
    {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear (String year)
    {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getDay ()
    {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay (String day)
    {
        this.day = day;
    }
}
```

I am trying to unmarshall these response in a single time by the following
but I am able to get the employee name,age. For the date of join element how do I get the element values in the unmarshall process. I dont want to do unmarshalling again.I could see that it is not a good way of programming

```
while(xsr1.hasNext()) {
            if(xsr1.isStartElement() && xsr1.getLocalName().equals("employee")) {
                JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class);
                Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
                Employee jb = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr1,Employee.class).getValue();
                System.out.println("Employee" + jb.getName()+"Age.getAge());
        }


            xsr1.next();

        }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Would like to see a bit of explanation also so that i can understand clearly based on the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dataofjoin should be already included inside the unmarshalled employee object

Comment: No. I just passed my XML response in http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/Convert URL. I could see that there are two class files. Dateofjoin's properties such as day,month,year  is not available in employee class.They are in a different class.

Comment: It doesn't matter they are in different classes. the Jaxb context knows about the Dateofjoin cause it traverse from the employee to the Dateofjoin, so the unmarshller knows how to handle elements belonging to Dateofjoin..